# Create files inside folders with spaces in name with bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create new folders with md files inside, and md files should have some text prepared inside. Problem is when folders have spaces in names. I have tried many different combinations with @, brackets and quotes but nothing worked.

This is current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir {folder1,folder2,'another folder'}

for f in $(ls -d -- */); do echo "---
tags: tag1, tag2
---" >> "$f"/mdfile.md; done
```

Comment: Are you passing folder names as variables from another file/output of another script  or directly in the script shown?

Comment: everything directly in script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `ls` there, or *ever* in a loop.  The output of `ls` is exclusively for looking at.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir folder1 folder2 'another folder' 

for f in */; do
    cat >>"$f"/mdfile.md <<END
---
tags: tag1, tag2
---
END
done
```

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)